# A way to stop Jenkins from executing a build over period of time, example: '5-7pm'?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

A way to stop Jenkins from executing a build over period of time, example: '5-7pm'

Example my session of Jenkins executes builds continuously, is there a way to stop a build from executing over a specific time period for example dont execute a build between 5-7pm?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799745/how-to-block-a-jenkins-job-from-running-at-certain-times

Comment: @Monis Majeed thanks i have tried this plugin but dosnt seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build continuously, I guess you're using SCM polling (eg. poll the SCM every 2 minutes). If that's the case, just configure polling to exclude the desired time-frame. This is done using standard "cron" syntax (help and examples are available from the Jenkins UI).